# Does anyone recognize these uniforms?

Tags: military, europe, identification, painting

Need assistance identifying the country of origin of a painting depicting men at war. I have also included pictures of the back in case anyone knows the language and can narrow it down. The language looks Armenian to me but I can’t be sure.

[image: Soldiers in a skirmish at a river]

[Here is a google drive link to the photos](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-nat0xFrH4hoHUuEkpJyEQgYPuYBcnAt)

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that the painting refers to real uniforms?

Comment: Given that the men's clothes are not actually *uniform* (one red guy and one blue guy on the right are clearly on the same side) I'm led to believe it's just traditional Armenian clothing of the depicted period.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I asked someone to translate and they said it referred to the murder of people named Musabek and a Mr. Hasa. Does that ring any bells? I couldn’t find much online other than a politician.